# How can I draw Flow chart using SmartGWT 2.2?

Tags: java, smartgwt, flowchart

I'm using SmartGWT 2.2 with Mozilla FF 3.6.x.

I need to create an application using smart gwt.
This application should be capable of making flow charts and diagram.
Diagrams will contain circle, rectangle, arrow etc.
By using this diagram One can Draw flow charts and other structures.

Is there any support or API available in smart gwt for this purpose?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about library for additional widgets support for Smartgwt, but you can achevie the implementation of flowchart or designing of flowchart even in Smartgwt with animation support (drag & drop). For shapes you can use various images or label / html panel (refer http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#effects_lf_corners). You can support dynamically adding text to these shapes/images also by using some events.